# Trying to understand asyncio with Python

Tags: python-3.x, concurrency, task, python-asyncio

I am trying to run some concurrent tasks with asyncio. Currently, i got the following example:

```
import asyncio
from time import sleep
from signal import SIGINT, SIGTERM, signal

async def f():
    print("Got in F")
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    print("Finished Sleep in F")
    return "f"


async def g():
    print("Got in G")
    await asyncio.sleep(20)
    print("Finished Sleep in G")
    return "g"

async def count_timer():
    for i in range(20):
        print(i)
        sleep(1)

async def main():
    
    task_g = asyncio.create_task(g())
    task_f = asyncio.create_task(f())
    

    await task_g
    await task_f

    task_counter = asyncio.create_task(count_timer())

    await task_counter

    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import time
    s = time.perf_counter()
    asyncio.run(main())
    elapsed = time.perf_counter() - s
    print(f"{__file__} executed in {elapsed:0.2f} seconds.")
```

What Im trying to do is to call the counter_timer function after the f and g functions were called, but still run all three concurrently.

Thank you in advance,
Lucas Delfino Nogueira.